# Allow mongoDB Atlas connection to cluster through ufw

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, mongodb, ufw, mongoose

Just what the title says, my ufw runs a tight ship and I have no idea how to let the atlas connection through.

I am extremely grateful for any help on this.

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and connect to the atlas cluster with mongoose in a nodejs app which listens to connections from the internet via nginx http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the internal configuration for `pm2`. I removed `pm2` along with the configuration and reinstalled.

Everything is working fine now without any further changes to `ufw`:

```
$ npm purge -g pm2

$ npm i -g pm2
```